# How to create PKCS #12 on ios -> more generally speaking how to transport rsa private/public key pair cross platform

Tags: ios, security, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have the following use case: user is syncing some data that a server used in exchange(sync) should not be trusted with.

The data is AES encrypted as following with 32 random bytes

the very same 32 bytes are encrypted with RSA public key and prefix that aes blob

now on the receiving end the user is supposed to enter his master password
to unlock the RSA private key to decode that 256 byte prefix to get the 32 byte
aes password. <strike>In a house that was built by Jack</strike>

Soooo, given the (idiotic imho) requirement that this should work cross
platform (how many folks do you know who have both vedroid and ios phones
or folk who transition from ios to android?)
I need some way to transport the private and public key to the
sync recipient device. Private key obviously needs to be well protected.

Thoughts on how to do handle all of this?

Android guy denies knowledge on how to make use of the binary public
key (happens to be 270 bytes extracted using

```
 - (NSData *)getPublicKey {

NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:self.publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

CFTypeRef inTypeRef = NULL;
// Get the key bits.
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, &inTypeRef);

NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;
if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess)
{
    publicKeyBits = (__bridge NSData *)inTypeRef;
}
return publicKeyBits;
}
```

and private key that somehow comes out at odd 1200 bytes using this

```
NSString *md5digest(NSString *masterpassword)
{
const char * pointer = [masterpassword UTF8String];
unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_MD5(pointer, (CC_LONG)strlen(pointer), md5Buffer);

NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [string appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

return string;
}

- (NSData *)getPrivatekey:(NSString*)md5digest
{
NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:self.privateTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

CFTypeRef inTypeRef = NULL;
// Get the key bits.
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, &inTypeRef);

NSData * publicKeyBits = nil;
if (sanityCheck == errSecSuccess)
{
    publicKeyBits = (__bridge NSData *)inTypeRef;

    NSData *key = [md5digest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *aes = [IDBAES256 AES256EncryptWithKey:key data:publicKeyBits];
    return aes;
}
return publicKeyBits;
}
```

claims his libraries on android need modulus and exponent to create RSA keypair
and he has no way to create them out of an array of uchars.

Thoughts?
I can obviously read .p12 just fine per
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html
but I see no API to pack two keys into a ceritificate on iOS
sorry about long winded question.
I've tried to keep the amount of code to the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using openssl to close gaps that security framework has in the functionality outlined in the OP